# Importing data from text file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

So, I am trying to develop a book database. I have created a table with 11 columns which populates a DGV, where only 6 columns are showed. The full data of each book is shown in a lower part of the form, where I have textboxes, which are bounded (BindingSource) to the table, that change as I move in the DGV.

Now, what I want to do is to have the posibility to export/import data from a file.

I have accomplished the exporting part with the following code:

```
Private Sub BtnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExport.Click

Dim txt As String = String.Empty

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DbdocsDataGridView.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                'Add the Data rows.
                txt += CStr(cell.Value & ","c)
            Next

            'Add new line.
            txt += vbCr & vbLf
        Next

Dim folderPath As String = "C:\CSV\"
        File.WriteAllText(folderPath & "DataGridViewExport.txt", txt)

    End Sub
```

However, I can't manage to import from the txt. What I've tried is this: https://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2018/04/vb.net-import-txt-file-text-to-datagridview.html
It works perfectly if you code the table and it populates de DGV without problem. I can't see how should I adapt that code to my need.

```
Private Sub BtnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnImport.Click

        DbdocsDataGridView.DataSource = table

        Dim filas() As String
        Dim valores() As String

        filas = File.ReadAllLines("C:\CSV\DataGridViewExport.txt")

        For i As Integer = 0 To filas.Length - 1 Step +1

            valores = filas(i).ToString().Split(",")

            Dim row(valores.Length - 1) As String

            For j As Integer = 0 To valores.Length - 1 Step +1
                row(j) = valores(j).Trim()

            Next j

            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next i

    End Sub
```

That is what I've tried so far, but I always have an exception arising.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me an insight about this.

Comment: Take a look at TextFieldParser,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: You may want to serialize/ deserialize to JSON your DataTable. It will preserve the schema and also the correct Type of each Column. -- In any case, I suggest to avoid to create your own *format*: it's not as simple as it may appear at first glance.

Comment: Thanks dbasnett and Jimi for their answers =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable class has built-in methods to load/save data from/to XML called `ReadXml` and `WriteXml`. Take a look at example which uses the overload to preserve the schema:

```vb
Private ReadOnly dataGridViewExportPath As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\", "CSV", "DataGridViewExport.txt")
Private Sub BtnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExport.Click
    table.WriteXml(path, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnImport.Click
    table.ReadXml(path)
End Sub
```

While users can manually edit the XML file that is generated from WriteXML, I would certainly not suggest it.

Comment: ¡You nailed it, man! I've made a few changes, but this is the answer.
`Dim filename As String = "C:\CSV\DataGridViewExport.txt"_DbdocsDataSet.WriteXml(filename)` for exporting, and `Dim filename As String = "C:\CSV\DataGridViewExport.txt"_DbdocsDataSet.ReadXml(filename)` for importing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is code which writes to a text file:

`speichern` means `to save`.
Note that I use a `#` in my example for formatting reasons. When reading in again, you can find the `#` and then you know that and that line is coming...
And I used `Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")` to format the Date into German format, but you can decide yourself if you want that. 
Note that I'm using a FileDialog that I downloaded from Visual Studio's own NuGet package manager.
[image: Download FileDialog in Visual Studio]

```
Private Sub Button_speichern_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_speichern.Click
        speichern()
    End Sub

    Private Sub speichern()
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' User can choose where to save the text file and the program will save it .
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim Path As String
        Using SFD1 As New CommonSaveFileDialog
            SFD1.Title = "store data in a text file"
            SFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Textdatei", ".txt"))
            SFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
            If SFD1.ShowDialog() = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = SFD1.FileName & ".txt"
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Using textfile As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Path, True, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            textfile.WriteLine("Timestamp of this file [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss]: " & Date.Now.ToString("G", Deu) & NewLine & NewLine) 'supposed to be line break + 2 blank lines :-)
            
            
                
                    textfile.WriteLine("your text")
                    textfile.WriteLine("#") 'Marker
            
            textfile.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        speichern()
    End Sub
```

And this is to read from a text file:

```
'read all Text
        Dim RAT() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Pfad, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        If RAT.Length = 0 Then Return Nothing

        For i As Integer = 0 To RAT.Length - 1 Step 1
            If RAT(i) = "#" OrElse RAT(i) = "" Then Continue For
            'do your work here with (RAT(i))
        Next
```